# Memory efficient transfer of large file from S3 to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have some working code below to transfer a file from S3 to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). From my understanding, this downloads the file into memory before uploading to GCS. I would like to find a more efficient way of doing this (in code). I realise Google has a transfer service and there are CLI options, but those aren't suitable for what I am doing.

Inside my app, the code below resides in small methods, but I've posted it in long procedural form to make it simpler to see the steps on here in one go.

```
# AWS S3: Connect and get object
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1', access_key_id: 'my_access_key', secret_access_key: 'my_secret')
response = s3.get_object(bucket:'my_s3_bucket', key:'my_object_key')

# Google Cloud Storage: Connect, Authorize and upload S3 object
client = Google::APIClient.new( :application_name => APP_NAME, :application_version => APP_VERSION )
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(P12_KEY, 'notasecret')

client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :token_credential_uri => 'token_credential_uri',
  :audience => 'audience',
  :scope => 'scope',
  :issuer => 'issuer',
  :signing_key => key)
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

storage = client.discovered_api('storage', 'v1')

media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(response['response'], 'text/csv', 'my_filename.txt')

resumable_result = client.execute(
  api_method: storage.objects.insert,
  media: media,
  parameters: {
    uploadType: 'resumable',
    bucket: 'my_gcs_bucket',
    name: filename.to_s
  },
  body_object: {contentType: 'text/csv'},
  connection: conn
)
```

I have seen ways to stream the object directly to a file on disk which avoids loading the entire object into memory, but how would I go about doing the same with GCS as the final target?

Comment: Ah, sorry should have been clearer, I mean more memory efficient. If I have a 3GB file and limited available memory for example.

Comment: How did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @Cemo,
I can't 100% remember, but I think I may have used / written a Google Cloud Function (GCF) to pull the files from S3, rather than them going via an intermediary Ruby app. Since writing this question, i've been using Python and GCFs to solve the majority of problems in my work; moving files and data around.

Answer (score 3):

you can either use `gsutil` (which supports [rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)) **or** create the transfers on the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-manage-transfer-program) (in case you insist on using Ruby and efficient in the same sentence). downloading and re-uploading might take ages, direct transfer is what I'd rather consider as efficient.

guess the equivalent in Ruby is the [APIClient/Request](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google-api-client/0.8.2/Google/APIClient/Request) - in order to create the requests, which are otherwise not explicitly supported by that Ruby API client.

while `gsutil rsync` can mirror whole buckets. always double and triple check it's parameters and their order, because when mirroring an empty directory/bucket, this can lead to sudden blackouts. would suggest to try with two merely empty buckets, at first - and then replace source & destination.

```
gsutil rsync -d -r s3://my-s3-bucket gs://my-gs-bucket
```

Comment: direct transfer is what I am essentially after

Comment: The Rest API documentation asks for the S3 keys so I assume the bucket can be private and it will still work.

Comment: @Anthony when providing the keys with the request already, this enables the API to authenticate server-side; not an issue then (useless comment removed).